# Advice on use of SCTP for sending BULK SMS over IP instead of PHYSICAL LINES

Tags: sms, bulk, sctp

I am investigating SCTP and whether its  useful for sending BULK SMS BUSSINESS in any way.So far my efforts have gone vain.I am not from telecom background.

So have faced some challeges to get acquainted.Perhaps any point of advice to use SCTP or ANY other part of SS7 leading to  enhacement of the process  of sending BULK SMS is highly appreciated.Many thanks for reading this

Answer (score 0):

SCTP in itself will get you nowhere - you need one of the user adaption layers (e.g. M3UA, SUA) - and then the rest of the stack (e.g. in case of M3UA: SCCP, TCAP, MAP). This however will only be useful if you are an mobile operator and have a mobile operator license from your countries telco regulator - as no other operator will have much to do with you without this.

Closest you might get is SMPP interface from a Mobile operator - but these are usually not easily provided. So you are left with working with some other provider which already has arrangements in place with the operators in your country. Though it is theoretically possible that one of them might require you to use SCTP - it will not be to carry SS7 (i.e. MAP).